# Public a As New Scripting.Dictionary in Word Macro

Tags: vba, dictionary, public

I have a simple Word Macro in a .DOTM file project. Really not very complicated.
There's mainly some functions and

```
Sub NameofSub(control As IRibbonControl) associated to Ribbon buttons.
```

Everything is fine until I write

```
Public test As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

in the first lines of the code, outside any function or sub. Doing this results in all `RibbonControls` telling me that the macro is not available. Guess it might have to do with security???

What I want is declaring all dictionaries as public to all my sub and functions so that I do not have to declare them in any sub so making changes easier.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (in VBE Tools - References...). Or use another approach: `Dim test as Object`, then `Set test = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.  Late or early binding (late binding for the last one)...

Comment: Thx for this hint but why does it work without a reference if i use it directly inside a sub?

Shouldn't it make problems than also?
So everything works fine if the

Dim Signature
Set Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Signature.Add "A", "test.RTF"

is inside a sub but the problems start moving the declaration outside the sub?

Ooooooohh guess i see the difference...

My code is creating an "Object".

The "public" declaration is directly creating the dictionary...

I will try to clear my eye glasses and test again...

Comment: The `Public` and `Private` are module level declarations. Inside a `Sub` you can only have `Dim` and `Const`.

Comment: If you need to use the dictionary in all existing subs, or in more then one, you will declare it of the module level. Something like `Private test as Object` (delete the declaration from the sub).  It works without reference, **not due to the fact it was declared on the `Sub` leves**. It works followed by `Set test = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. This means late binding... The early binding allows simple declaring `Private test As New Scripting.Dictionary` and you will benefit of intellisense, too. Being able to see the object properties (method, if the case) only writing the obj...

Comment: is your code it a plain-old module? Or is it in a class, or other type of code-behind module?

Comment: I can put the Declaration into the module

Private test As New Scripting.Dictionary

but at the moment i try to write values into the dictionary to initialize it my macros are all "lost".

test.Add "a", "bbb"

does not work.

Comment: You have posted insufficient code for anyone to make a worthwhile contribution.  Please follow the guidelines for posting code and edit your post so that there is a minimum compilable example of the problem.